# How do I create a rounded rectangle in a rounded corner WPF form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating an application in WPF and I wanted rounded corners. I got that. Now that the form is borderless, I am trying to create a rounded rectangle and place it at the top so that it looks like the top bar of a Windows application.

I am unable to do so.

Here is my code:

```
<Border CornerRadius="50, 0, 50, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="GhostWhite">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,402">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="796">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Border Width="800" Height="200" CornerRadius="50,0,0,0" Background="DarkOliveGreen"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="403" Margin="0,44,0,-403" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="796"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

My main form:

[image: Main Form Design]
What I want:

[image: Desired Output]

What I am getting:

[image: My Output]

Comment: the border as a control does not limit the content and force it inside its border you could work with an opacity mask to fix that

Comment: I even tried adding another `<Border>` for the rectangle, separately. It said `The property "Content" is set more than once`.

Comment: Will the window be fixed size? I would suggest clip on the window. You need a geometry to define that. Windowchrome would be a candidate but the cornerradius for that seems bugged and won't match a border you put inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and worked.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WpfTester.Controls" x:Class="WpfTester.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000" Loaded="Window_Loaded" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.0" Color="White"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Border CornerRadius="50, 0, 0, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" Background="DarkOliveGreen">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" Background="White">
        <Grid Name="Body">

        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="0, 0, 50, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2" Background="White">
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

you can add your contents on  which named "Body"

**Added** : Changed my solution cuz of background:white area on rounded edges.

Comment: @Andy Modified.

Comment: Wouldn't x:null be more appropriate if you don't want it there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some minor changes to your control structure to achieve it. Following code is tested and working.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=myBorder}" />
    </Grid.OpacityMask>
    <Border x:Name="myBorder" CornerRadius="50,0,50,0" Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="796">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border Width="800" Height="200" CornerRadius="50,0,0,0" Background="DarkOliveGreen"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```